# Creating a type bound to a certain range in Swift

Tags: swift, types, swift3

Say I have a function that takes an `Int`, but not just any `Int`. It could be:

- Only natural numbers
- `Ints` from 2 to 200
- etc

Assume that the number of valid values is too big to make the use of an `Enum` that explicitly declares all of them a feasible approach.

Is there a way to declare a type that specifies a closed range in Swift?

I tried playing around with `Range`, but it doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can think of is to wrap an `Int` in a struct with an initializer that enforces your condition:

```
struct NameMe {
    let value: Int

    init?(_ value: Int) {
        guard 2...200 ~= value else { return nil }
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Whereas using `Int` alone would require a run-time condition check at every place a value of such a kind was needed, this technique limits this to only the places where such values are created in the first place. Once created, you can pass around `NameMe` instances around, knowing that their value meets the preconditions.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **stored property** to store actual value and use  ***Computed Property*** to get and set value to **stored property** . So do some validation in ***set*** in ***Computed Property*** . that way u can restrict the value